# Environnement variable missing in Django

Tags: django, geodjango

I am have issue with my GeoDjango app and I think it is linked a missing environment variable.

I have the following error on a simple GeoJSONLayerView:

```
GDALException at /GeoJSONTrialView/9020/
OGR failure.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://realregatta.com/GeoJSONTrialView/9020/
Django Version: 3.0.6
Exception Type: GDALException
Exception Value:    
OGR failure.
Exception Location: /opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/error.py in check_err, line 59
Python Executable:  /opt/bitnami/python/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.7
```

I found a workaround by adding the environment variable in the view:

```
class GeoJSONTrialView(GeoJSONLayerView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        os.environ["PROJ_LIB"]  = "/home/bitnami/stack/postgresql/share/proj"
        context = Trial.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
```

Note that I have the variable set in my settings.py (and it shows on the Django debug crash page, even without my workaround):

```
PROJ_LIB  = "/home/bitnami/stack/postgresql/share/proj"
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://realregatta.com/GeoJSONTrialView/9020/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.7.7
Installed Applications:
['RR.apps.AppConfig',
 'djgeojson',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.gis']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djgeojson/views.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return super(GeoJSONLayerView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 158, in get
    return self.render_to_response(context)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djgeojson/views.py", line 79, in render_to_response
    **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djgeojson/serializers.py", line 475, in serialize
    self.end_serialization()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djgeojson/serializers.py", line 258, in end_serialization
    json.dump(self.feature_collection, self.stream, cls=cls, **self.options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 325, in _iterencode_list
    yield from chunks
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djgeojson/serializers.py", line 71, in default
    return json.loads(o.geojson)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 387, in json
    return self.ogr.json
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 429, in ogr
    return gdal.OGRGeometry(self._ogr_ptr(), self.srs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 436, in srs
    return gdal.SpatialReference(self.srid)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/srs.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.import_epsg(srs_input)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/srs.py", line 277, in import_epsg
    capi.from_epsg(self.ptr, epsg)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/errcheck.py", line 117, in check_errcode
    check_err(result, cpl=cpl)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/error.py", line 59, in check_err
    raise e(msg)

Exception Type: GDALException at /GeoJSONTrialView/9020/
Exception Value: OGR failure.
```

Not sure what to do to avoid my workaround...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the code below in my wsgi.py. Maybe not the best place but it works and avoid me to add it to each view:

```
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"]  = "/home/bitnami/stack/postgresql/share/proj"
```